# WebBrowser with close button in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone app, I need to show a **webbrowser with a close button** when the app launches for first time. The webbrowser is placed on the landing page and how can i place a close button on the browser so that the user can close that webbrowser by clicking on that button to view the contents on the landing page. The webbrowser is intended to display an Ad. I tried using pop up, but the pop up can have only one child.

How can I do this in windows phone, Please help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put them in PopUp - wrap them into `StackPanel`. So it can be placed into PopUp.

```
   <StackPanel>
       <Button/>
       <WebBrowser/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, but how can I place that button on the web browser? I want the close button to be placed on the top right corner so that the user can click that button to close the popup.

Comment: Instead of StackPanel you can use Grid, or Border and set the margin for button to change it's position.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using some of the controls in the Coding4Fun toolkit on codeplex.

http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/